# can we place OS version specific images other than app icon or launch image in Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

We can place iOS specific app icon and launch image in Asset Catalog. Can we place other images used for buttons, bars or other UI elements in the Asset Catalog to be used with specific iOS versions? Or there is only way to do these programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It would have been really nice, if Apple had developed a more flexible asset management, like Android (for example) has since many years...

Regarding your question: According to the official documentation, there is no such way (at least I could not read anything about it) at the moment (iOS 7).